# discard qualifiers error when in C++ with map pointer is changed as value

Tags: c++, c++11

I had this (simplified) code that works fine.

```
class T
{
    map<string, int>* m;
public:    

    T()
    {
        m = new map<string, int>();
    }
    void get(const string& key, int& val) const
    {
        val = (*m)[key];
    }
}
```

When I changed the pointer into value,

```
class T
{
    map<string, int> m;
public:    

    void get(const string& key, int& val) const
    {
        val = m[key];
    }

};
```

I got this error message, what is wrong?

```
In member function 'void T::get(const string&, int&) const':
constTest.cpp:12:20: error: passing 'const std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>' 
as 'this' argument of 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& ...' 
discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         val = m[key];
                    ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `get` method is `const`, all data members, including the `m`, are treated as constants. However, [the `[]` operator on a `map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/) is *not* constant. Use the [`at` method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/) instead, it has a `const` overload:

```
val = m.at(key);
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the `const` method, the type of the first container becomes effectively `map<string, int>* const` (the *pointer* is const, the pointee is not). The type of the second container becomes `const map<string, int>`.

The `operator[]` requires the object to be non-const because it may have to mutate to add a new element if one cant' be found. Thus in the first case the dereferenced pointer still points to a non-const container within the const function while the second case the container itself becomes treated as const.

What do you want to happen if the key you're searching for doesn't exist? If you want it to be created, your get function can't be const.

If you don't want it to be created, then use the map's `find` method to find the item you want (or `end()` if it can't be found, then deciding on suitable behavior).